# How can I do this in CSS? Transparent background on an element inside another element with background

Tags: css

is this possible? My CSS isn't bad, but I can't cannot wrap my hear around this. I want to use a background image behind a header, but I want the header to "knock out" the background image leaving the background either side. I hope that makes sense.

I've made a fiddle incase anyone wants to have a bash...Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/CnVBU/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is with `border-image`. See your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/CnVBU/3/).

Here's the CSS for it (multiple browsers):

```
.container { 
    border-width: 20px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/163/2/d/PixelBackground_02_by_Kara1984.jpg) 27 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/163/2/d/PixelBackground_02_by_Kara1984.jpg) 27 round;
    border-image: url(http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/163/2/d/PixelBackground_02_by_Kara1984.jpg) 27 round;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I generated this code with [Border-Image.com](http://border-image.com) (because writing this yourself is confusing as all hell :P).

Comment: Wow, I just took a look. When you move the slider the code really changes, I have NO idea how long it would take to figure it out without that site to help. Thank you very much for the link, I've never used that CSS rule....

Comment: Heh, yup, I was trying to do it myself and lucked upon that site. It's probably the only really confusing property. Also keep in mind that it's CSS3, so it's incompatible with older browsers. (And use a large image. Otherwise it'll look a bit weird).

Answer (score 0):

Well it is transparent now.  It sounds like what you want is to apply a background color matching some other color (body background color?) to the h1.  Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CnVBU/1/

Obviously using whatever background color you want and adding margin/padding etc. to give you the proper "knock-out" size.

Comment: Hi, I see what you've done but I need it to be literally punch out, not like an illusion....I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You might be limited to actually placing the transparency in the div's background image, or duplicating what is behind the div into the background of the h1.

Answer (score 0):

I've update your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CnVBU/2/

Now you got transparent background on h1.

I've use rgba color model: Red (range: 0-255) Green (0-255) Blue (0-255) Alfa (0-1).
If you want 50% transparency use 0.5 alfa there.

This works in all common browsers (most IE will need filter / hack for it)

Comment: Hi, I mean I want to literally see whatever would be behind the dix. It's not going to be a flat colour - that would be easy!